# iOS' equivalent to [NSColor colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace]

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, uicolor, nscolor

What is UIColor's equivalent to NSColor's:

```
NSColor *newColor = [someColor colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace]
```

Not even UIColor, but anything supported on iOS that does the same thing would be fine.

Comment: I don't believe there is a native iOS method of doing this. If you could specify exactly what you're trying to accomplish, it might be easier for someone to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple equivalent, you'll need to do a bit of work to extract the components from `someColor` (based on the colour space of the `CGColor`) , then create a new color using `CGColorCreate`. But you'll need to convert the colour components yourself.